# Select columns in PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for a way to select columns of my dataframe in PySpark. For the first row, I know I can use `df.first()`, but not sure about columns given that they do **not have column names.**

I have 5 columns and want to loop through each one of them.

```
+--+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|_1| _2| _3| _4| _5| _6| _7|
+--+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|1 |0.0|0.0|0.0|1.0|0.0|0.0|
|2 |1.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|
|3 |0.0|0.0|1.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
df.select([c for c in df.columns if c in ['_2','_4','_5']]).show()
```

Comment: I do not want to hard code because I would have to do this for hundreds of columns. So I want to loop through the columns do some analysis.

Comment: @Nivi, i've updated my answer - is that what you want?

Comment: Ah! that is a straight fwd way that I have been using for so long. I just went blank now. Thanks MAx :)

Comment: @rishijain, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46813599/revisions ;-) [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46813283/select-columns-in-pyspark-dataframe/46813599?noredirect=1#comment80574310_46813599)

Comment: this helped me.

Answer (score 35):

First two columns and 5 rows

```
 df.select(df.columns[:2]).take(5)
```

Answer (score 26):

You can use an array and unpack it inside the select:

```
cols = ['_2','_4','_5']
df.select(*cols).show()
```

Comment: This solution worked for my problem, but what does the `*` operator do?

Comment: @yeliabsalohcin * operator is to un pack the array. Pysparks select function does not accept an array.

Comment: be careful if you have special characters like '.' in your column names, then you have surround each string with backticks '`'

Comment: Can you help me implement this? Select multiple column names that contain '.' ?

Comment: Yes @charlie_boy , for this case, you can filter the column names using list comprehension: cols = [x for x in columns if "." in x]. Here, columns is a list with your column names. Also, be carefull with "." character in your column names, it have to be with backticks.

Answer (score 7):

The method [`select`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=select#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.select) accepts a list of column names (string) or expressions (Column) as a parameter. To select columns you can use:

-- column names (strings):

```
df.select('col_1','col_2','col_3')
```

-- column objects:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.select(F.col('col_1'), F.col('col_2'), F.col('col_3'))

# or

df.select(df.col_1, df.col_2, df.col_3)

# or

df.select(df['col_1'], df['col_2'], df['col_3'])
```

-- a list of column names or column objects:

```
df.select(*['col_1','col_2','col_3'])

#or

df.select(*[F.col('col_1'), F.col('col_2'), F.col('col_3')])

#or 

df.select(*[df.col_1, df.col_2, df.col_3])
```

The star operator `*` can be omitted as it's used to keep it consistent with other functions like `drop` that don't accept a list as a parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Use `df.schema.names`:

```python
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

df = spark.createDataFrame([("foo", 1), ("bar", 2)])
df.show()
# +---+---+ 
# | _1| _2|
# +---+---+
# |foo|  1| 
# |bar|  2|
# +---+---+

df.schema.names
# ['_1', '_2']

for i in df.schema.names:
  # df_new = df.withColumn(i, [do-something])
  print i
# _1
# _2
```

Answer (score 4):

The dataset in `ss.csv` contains some columns I am interested in:

```py
ss_ = spark.read.csv("ss.csv", header= True, 
                      inferSchema = True)
ss_.columns
```

```
['Reporting Area', 'MMWR Year', 'MMWR Week', 'Salmonellosis (excluding Paratyphoid fever andTyphoid fever)†, Current week', 'Salmonellosis (excluding Paratyphoid fever andTyphoid fever)†, Current week, flag', 'Salmonellosis (excluding Paratyphoid fever andTyphoid fever)†, Previous 52 weeks Med', 'Salmonellosis (excluding Paratyphoid fever andTyphoid fever)†, Previous 52 weeks Med, flag', 'Salmonellosis (excluding Paratyphoid fever andTyphoid fever)†, Previous 52 weeks Max', 'Salmonellosis (excluding Paratyphoid fever andTyphoid fever)†, Previous 52 weeks Max, flag', 'Salmonellosis (excluding Paratyphoid fever andTyphoid fever)†, Cum 2018', 'Salmonellosis (excluding Paratyphoid fever andTyphoid fever)†, Cum 2018, flag', 'Salmonellosis (excluding Paratyphoid fever andTyphoid fever)†, Cum 2017', 'Salmonellosis (excluding Paratyphoid fever andTyphoid fever)†, Cum 2017, flag', 'Shiga toxin-producing Escherichia coli, Current week', 'Shiga toxin-producing Escherichia coli, Current week, flag', 'Shiga toxin-producing Escherichia coli, Previous 52 weeks Med', 'Shiga toxin-producing Escherichia coli, Previous 52 weeks Med, flag', 'Shiga toxin-producing Escherichia coli, Previous 52 weeks Max', 'Shiga toxin-producing Escherichia coli, Previous 52 weeks Max, flag', 'Shiga toxin-producing Escherichia coli, Cum 2018', 'Shiga toxin-producing Escherichia coli, Cum 2018, flag', 'Shiga toxin-producing Escherichia coli, Cum 2017', 'Shiga toxin-producing Escherichia coli, Cum 2017, flag', 'Shigellosis, Current week', 'Shigellosis, Current week, flag', 'Shigellosis, Previous 52 weeks Med', 'Shigellosis, Previous 52 weeks Med, flag', 'Shigellosis, Previous 52 weeks Max', 'Shigellosis, Previous 52 weeks Max, flag', 'Shigellosis, Cum 2018', 'Shigellosis, Cum 2018, flag', 'Shigellosis, Cum 2017', 'Shigellosis, Cum 2017, flag']
```

*but I only need a few:*

```
columns_lambda = lambda k: k.endswith(', Current week') or k == 'Reporting Area' or k == 'MMWR Year' or  k == 'MMWR Week'
```

The filter returns the list of desired columns, list is  evaluated:

```
sss = filter(columns_lambda, ss_.columns)
to_keep = list(sss)
```

the list of desired columns is unpacked as arguments to dataframe select function that return dataset containing only columns in the list:

```py
dfss = ss_.select(*to_keep)
dfss.columns
```

The result:

```
['Reporting Area',
 'MMWR Year',
 'MMWR Week',
 'Salmonellosis (excluding Paratyphoid fever andTyphoid fever)†, Current week',
 'Shiga toxin-producing Escherichia coli, Current week',
 'Shigellosis, Current week']
```

The `df.select()` has a complementary pair: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.drop

to drop the list of columns.