# Can't display a column in a PySpark SQLContext DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

Sorry for the noob question but I've been stuck for hours on that problem :

If I type :

```
df['avg_wind_speed_9am'].head()
```

It returns :

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-42-c01967246c17> in <module>() ----> 1 df['avg_wind_speed_9am'].head() TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

And if I type :

```
df[['avg_wind_speed_9am']].head()
```

It returns :

```
Row(avg_wind_speed_9am=2.080354199999768)
```

I don't understand, normally it should print a column.

Here is how I imported the dataframe :

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.load('file:///home/cloudera/Downloads/big-data-4/daily_weather.csv', format='com.databricks.spark.csv', header='true', inferSchema='true')
```

Here is how my dataset looks like :

```
number,air_pressure_9am,air_temp_9am,avg_wind_direction_9am,avg_wind_speed_9am,max_wind_direction_9am,max_wind_speed_9am,rain_accumulation_9am,rain_duration_9am,relative_humidity_9am,relative_humidity_3pm
0,918.0600000000087,74.82200000000041,271.1,2.080354199999768,295.39999999999986,2.863283199999908,0.0,0.0,42.42000000000046,36.160000000000494
1,917.3476881177097,71.40384263106537,101.93517935618371,2.4430092157340217,140.47154847112498,3.5333236016106238,0.0,0.0,24.328697291802207,19.4265967985621
```

Comment: Can you please share your dataframe in the text form?

Comment: please post the dataframe in the form of text

Comment: Your error messages and output look like `pyspark`, not `pandas`.

Comment: Damn, I didn't know pyspark and pandas were different about that. Yes, I'm on pyspark.

Comment: Subscribing to what @Michael Szczesny said - I would try: `df.select('avg_wind_speed_9am').head()` to keep it more conventional

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select columns in Pyspark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46813283/select-columns-in-pyspark-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the below:

```py
df.select('avg_wind_speed_9am').head()

df.select('avg_wind_speed_9am').show()
n = 10
df.select('avg_wind_speed_9am').take(n)
```

Generally in `pyspark` you query dataframe, and not individual columns, hence to query single column you need to use:

`df.select(<list_of_cols>)` where `<list_of_cols>` is a single column in your case.